# How to remove Provisioning file completely?

Tags: iphone

I want to install developed application to mobile. There is an application already installed in the device. I can remove the application however I am unable to remove provisioning file. When I drag and drop the provisioning file existing one get replaced and application is not running properly.

Comment: so your problem is unable to instal app into your device?

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Press command + space --- (Spotlight) Search for iPhoneConfigurationUtility

Goto iPhoneConfigurationUtility --- > Click Provisioning Profiles..

You will get a list...

Select one of them which you want to delete and press delete

Comment: I have install this software and it did not display my required Provisioning file related to app. Others are displaying

Comment: You got the list of provisional profiles rite ? the one which you want to delete is there in the list of provisional profiles or not ? @harshdissanayake